# How do you use Comparators to make a circuit which switches based upon a specific voltage?

Tags: voltage, led, circuit-analysis, voltage-measurement, comparator

This is a simple question I just have no idea how to build a circuit which incorporates this kind of logic.

I have a line which will either be 0-0.4V or 1-3V. I want to run a different circuit for 0-0.4V than for the 1-3V.

For the sake of clarity in this example - lets say I want to light up a red LED if its 0-0.4v and I want to light a green LED for 1-3V.

Can somebody show me how to do this? Which components I need and what their role is in the solution?

Comment: two comparators should be just fine

Comment: Can you please show me the way I would wire up the comparator for this particular use case. I am needing help understanding how to use the comparator. A circuit perhaps using CircuitLab would be very helpful.

Comment: I suggest you read up about how a comparator works, then try something and when you are stuck about a specific thing there, come back with what you already tried.

Comment: You can use simple AOP to make the comparator. It's a very simple circuit. Google may teach you how to build it

Comment: PlasmaHH can you give a good link describing how it works? Wikipedia isnt great and im struggling to understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this purpose, think of a comparator as comparing a unknown voltage to a reference.  The result is a digital signal that indicates the unknown voltage is above or below the reference.

You want to know if some voltage is below 400 mV, and if it is above 1.0 V.  You have two values to compare the incoming voltage to, so you need two comparators.

You should be able to figure out the rest.  We are here to help with the concepts and the theory, but this isn't a *gimme da codz* kind of site.

Comment: This is useful Olin thank you. How do you tell the comparator  what the two voltages you want to compare against are ?

Comment: @Rene: You feed it to them on one of their inputs.

Comment: And how do I feed 400mV to my input! This is why I am trying to say one question leads to another -- it would really really help me to see an end to end flow!

Comment: @Rene: Then you are asking too high a level of question.  You apparently need to learn some basics before you're ready to use comparators.  Again, this isn't a *gimme da codz* site.

Comment: Olin, so do comparators come in many different forms, like a 0.5v , 0.6v, 0.7v etc ?

Comment: @Reneg: No.  They compare to whatever voltage you feed them, within their useful input range of course.

Comment: Can you do me a favor and link me to a comparator which would have a range of 0 - 5v? I am struggling to find such a chip ( although I know they exist because you reference them!) a link to a place to buy one would be great.

Comment: @Reneg: Something like a MCP600x opamp makes a reasonably forgiving and easy to use comparator for your purpose.